# skaffold - ingress error - host and path already defined

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skaffold

When running skaffold dev command, I get this error:

```
- for: "STDIN": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: host "ticketing.dev" and path "/api/users/?(.*)" is already defined in ingress default/ingress-service
time="2021-06-20T19:55:11+03:00" level=warning msg="Skipping deploy due to error: kubectl apply: exit status 1"
```

when I change the path "/api/users/?(.*)" to something like "/api/usersssss/?(.*)", the error dissapears

restarting my machine doesn't help

any que?

ingress-srv.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

skaffold.yaml:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta17
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: tickets
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: natankamusher/auth
    context: auth
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - infra/k8s/auth-depl.yaml
    - infra/k8s/ingress-srv.yaml
```

Comment: Seems like the app is runing but the console is'nt active

Comment: What local cluster are you running? Minikube 1.19 had a bug that manifests as you describe here (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11121).  That has ben fixed in minikube 1.20.0.

Comment: I'm running on windows

Comment: Could you include the output of running `skaffold dev -vdebug` and `kubectl describe --all-namespaces ingress`?  That will output a lot of help information for diagnosing what's going on.  It sounds like you have an ingress already defined?

Answer (score 1):

run the below command to

```
kubectl delete Ingress ingress-srv
```

ingress-srv is the name of the service